# After zooming image on UIScrollview, it scroll outside of image areas

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a image zooming functionality using `UIScrollview`. where as I kept image as aspect fit.
Image is inside a `UIScrollView`, and image frame has been given similar to `UIScrollView`.
Here is my code.

```
class CroppingImageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{    
    var image:UIImage = UIImage()

    @IBOutlet var imageview:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollview:UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        imageview.image = image
        scrollview.contentSize = imageview.frame.size;
        scrollview.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
        scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
        scrollview.setZoomScale(scrollview.minimumZoomScale, animated: true)
        scrollview.delegate = self;
    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageview
    }
}
```

[What's actually happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilXh6.png)
[What required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXirC.png)
My requirement is that the image should be scrolled up to it's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

As per the apple documentation the automaticAdjustScrollViewInsets by default YES.

So its trying to control your scrollview.

add this in your viewdidload method and then try.

Comment: It's still the same. No luck !!

Answer (score 0):

i was searching for same thing for a while. and i did like this. its kind a worked for me.

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image

        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

        ScrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size

        let scrollViewFrame = ScrollView.frame
        let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / ScrollView.contentSize.width
        let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height/ScrollView.contentSize.height

        let minScale = min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth)

        ScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
        ScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1
        ScrollView.zoomScale = minScale
        ScrollView.clipsToBounds = true

        centerScrollViewContents()

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

 func centerScrollViewContents(){
    let boundsSize = ScrollView.bounds.size
        var contentsFrame = imageView.frame

        if contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width{
            contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width)/2

        }else{
            contentsFrame.origin.x = 0
        }

        if contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height{
            contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height)/2
        }else{
            contentsFrame.origin.y = 0
        }

        imageView.frame = contentsFrame
    }
```